# Make a win32 console app display a window

Tags: winapi, console

I've been developing a win32 console app and now I'd like it to be able to optionally show a non modal status / notification window. Is there any way I can do this from a console app or will I need to rewrite it as a windows app?

This is for a kiosk system so I'll need to call SetWindowPos() with the topmost flag on the window handle.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember the main difference is that you'll need a message pump. This question describes a basic message pump: [Why are "TranslateMessage" and "DispatchMessage" separate calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152011/why-are-translatemessage-and-dispatchmessage-separate-calls)

This tutorial might also be helpful: [Understanding the Message Loop](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html)

Comment: I saw the code project article while googling for a solution to this requirement. While it's a perfectly viable method, it does require a thread and a message pump. I was hoping for something more along the lines of a non modal MessageBox() lookalike.

Comment: @Simon Elliott: You don't need another thread, but how would you expect your window to work without a message pump?

Comment: @jamesdlin: I was hoping that the message pump could be encapsulated or at least a little bit less visible.

Answer (score 0):

see a `CreateWindow` / `CreateWindowEx` functions