# Link windows.h (WNDCLASSEX) code in VS2010 console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I have a VS2010 Win32 console application. Within this console application I try to attach a window as child to **another** Win32 app. But I do not get the application **linked** (it compiles, just the linker issue AFAIK):

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __stdcall viewproc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?viewproc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl createFSXWindow(void)" (?createFSXWindow@@YAXXZ)  H:\Projects\VisualStudioNet2010\FSXTests\Menu Items\Menu Items\MenuItems.obj    Menu Items
```

I have added all libs from a Win32 Windows project under Linker/include:

```
kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib; comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib; odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

Remark: Just to clarify, I do NOT(!) try to attach the window to the console window, but another Win32 application, so it is not about ["Make a win32 console app display a window"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193433/make-a-win32-console-app-display-a-window)

The issue comes in once I add the window code such as:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
....

// window
WNDCLASSEX wc;
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
wc.lpfnWndProc = viewproc;
```

When I check the command line of the linker the only difference between my console app and an Win32 app is `SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` vs. `SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker error just tells you that you forgot to *write* the viewproc() function.

You declared it, the compiler is happy, but didn't implement it, the linker is unhappy.  Or you wrote it but mistyped the definition.  It is not a function that's implemented in one of the standard libraries, you have to provide it.  The window procedure is what you use to give a window custom behavior.

Comment: Gosh, lucky me since wc.lpfnWndProc was just in the above code example by chance. I was looking in the wrong direction, thanks!